# Sinch Register User in php

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, sinch

I created instant messaging use [Sinch](https://www.sinch.com/products/instant-messaging/), is possible to Create user Sinch in php (Codeigniter)?

nb: I will create api to register to sinch, but sinch only available in JS

Thank you,
Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

What you should really do is to to use your own user database i.e in PHP/Parse and use delegated security when you start the sinch client. You dont need to have a user registered with sinch (our user handling is just for demo purposes)

There is a couple of samples https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/using-delegated-security-application-server-using-c-sinch-sdk/ and with the SDK there is python sample for generating a user ticket.

Here is a python sample

https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/authentication-php-sinch-javascript-sdk/